# How can I update all NFTS minted from Candy Machine V3?

Tags: nfts, candy-machine-v3, upgrade

I've inserted 22k NFTs to candy machine v3 and some of NFTS are already minted.
I need to update the NFTs metadata.
there's a source code for updating NFT metadata in candy machine v2 but not found for candy machine v3.
Please help me.